# How to avoid display of HTML tags in mail function

Tags: php, html

I have a mail function, and it works fine, I get mails. But the problem is that I also get the HTML tags as it is. I have code as follows:

```
$from=$_REQUEST['id'];  
$to  = 'xyz@abc.com';  

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

$headers = "From: $from \r\n" .  
    "Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();  

$subject="Contact Mail has received";  

$message=" SOME HTML TAGS ";
```

Inside the message body, I have HTML tags like `table`, `tr`, `td`, etc. But when I receive the mail, I don't get the table. I get all the HTML tags as `table`, `tr`, `td`. In header, I have even specified content type as `text/html`, but still I have the same issue.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: use a mail class so you can send text and html emails
sample : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't specified `text/html` because you are overwritting you headers!

Here, you assign it then overwrite it:

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

$headers = "From: $from \r\n" .  
       "Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
       "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

It should be

```
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";  
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  

$headers .= "From: $from \r\n" .  
       "Reply-To: $from \r\n" .  
       "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

You missed a dot to append more headers.  This overwrites your Content-Type and that is why it is parsing the email as text and not has HTML